# what is mean of the NOTE description

Tags: ember.js

> `NOTE: If you define a resource using this.resource and do not supply a function, then the implicit resource.index route is not created. In that case, /resource will only use the ResourceRoute, ResourceController, and resource template.`

I see this info on [emberjs.com](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) when writing code, but nothing works on the page. [This](http://jsbin.com/ikituj/46/edit) is my page.

Answer (score 0):

First I am not sure what you've meant by extending Route(s), s is not defined.

For the main reason you don't see anything, views are hierarchical, you must have an application view, which is the parent of the blogs view with an {{outlet}} defined, otherwise the whole chain won't get rendered.

Look at the fixed revision:
http://jsbin.com/ikituj/52/

Comment: oh,thank you.
now ,i modify my code,  when link to 'blogs' first, render the 'blogs/index' template, then click blogcategory the 'blogs/list' will show by category .

http://jsbin.com/ikituj/58/edit